# Irreducible polynomial and primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Let $n$ be a prime number. How can I show that the polynomial $f(x) = x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} + x^{n-3}+ \cdots + x+ 1$ is irreducible over any finite field?

Comment: Any field is not right. Take for example the complex numbers.

Comment: It is not irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_n$, because $1+\mathbb{Z}$ is a root.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I made a mistake. Of course I meant finite fields.

Comment: Indeed, this is not true. Take Questioner's example.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578642/irreducible-polynomial-over-a-finite-field or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433779/factoring-polynomials-of-the-form-1x-cdots-xp-1-in-finite-field ?

Comment: It's not true over all finite fields, either: if $n > 2$, take a finite field and adjoin all roots of $f$, yielding a (possibly larger) finite field in which $f$ isn't irreducible.

Comment: $\;f(x)=x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\ldots+x+1\;$ has $\;1\;$ as a root in $\;\Bbb F_p\;$ and is thus **reducible** there.